# What is the difference between deb file and ddeb file in linux?

Tags: dpkg, debian

I need to install `SystemTap` on Ubuntu 14 and I would need to install debug symbols for kernel . I need brief explanation about  ddeb file , why it should have different extension ?

Answer (score 7):

There is an automatic process to create the debugging packages that you are after with 2 aims:

1. Spare developers the need to produce a separate package
2. Save space for mirrored repositories

This process creates the `.ddeb` files that you are looking at. To confuse the issue older debug packages will still be available for the foreseeable future with the `.deb` suffix...

**References:**

- [Ubuntu Wiki: Debug Symbols](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AptElfDebugSymbols)
- [Debian Wiki: Automatic Debug Packages](https://wiki.debian.org/AutomaticDebugPackages)